# OptionError:'Pattern matched multiple keys' pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xls

I am trying to read a excel file.

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.nepalstock.com/todaysprice/export'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('todayprice.xls', 'wb').write(r.content)

import pandas as pd
pd.set_option("xls", "openpyxl")
fileurl='todayprice.xls'
df=pd.read_excel(fileurl)
print(df)
```

I get an error saying:

```
raise OptionError("Pattern matched multiple keys")
pandas._config.config.OptionError: 'Pattern matched multiple keys'
```

Answer (score 25):

This error often happens when people use older codes for pandas options, like `precision`. Starting in 1.4 some of these are replaced with longer forms, like `display.precision`.

Solution: visit [list of options in pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html) and find the updated name for your option.

I'd like to add that the error message `Pattern matched multiple keys` is quite confusing. Pandas team may want to change it.

Answer (score 13):

In the new Pandas version, you need to use the code below to get the desired output.

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = 5
```

Comment: Never write something like "the new pandas version", it'll age terribly. Be specific: "pandas 1.4+" or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the option `io.excel.xls.reader` instead of just `xls`.

From [the doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html):

> Regexp which should match a single option. Note: partial matches are
> supported for convenience, but unless you use the full option name
> (e.g. x.y.z.option_name), your code may break in future versions if
> new options with similar names are introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Both
Pd.set_option("display.max_columns",100)
And
Pd.options.display.max_columns=100

Perform the same role

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 100)` solved my problem.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html

Answer (score 0):

Tried various methods like: pd.set_option('max_columns', 35)

but the below format will surely help:

**pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 100)**

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html